# Swift / How to fix: TableView bottom cells missing in size of the UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using [this Framework](https://github.com/davidseek/SLPagingViewSwift-Swift-3-Tinder-Twitter) to have a moving `UINavigationBar`. I have the following problem with every View (since every view has a `UITableView` or `UICollectionView` - Yes this bug appears with `UICollectionView`, too)

[image]

The bottom of every Screen is missing in the size of the `UINavigationBar`.

The controller is a subclass of `UIViewController`.

```
open class SLPagingViewSwift: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate
```

The `UIViewControllers` are created globally:

```
var settingsVC: UserSettingsVC?
```

Instantiated within the class that creates the controller:

```
appDelegate.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

settings = settingsStb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "UserSettingsVC") as? UserSettingsV
// among other VCs
self.setItems() //sets the images at the navigationbar               
let items = [itemsArray]

let controllers = [arrayOfVCs] as [UIViewController]

controller = SLPagingViewSwift(items: items, controllers: controllers, showPageControl: false)
controller.indexSelected = 1

nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = nav
appDelegate.window?.backgroundColor = cachedBlack
appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

The example controller is a `UITableViewController`. Same bug appears in every other `UIViewController` with a `UITableView` as well as in one `UITableViewController` with a `UICollectionView`.

What am I missing? Help is very appreciated.

Comment: Maybe it have something to do with `contentInset` try change the value and see

Comment: `collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 44, 0)` / `tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 44, 0)` did it. feel free to answer. even tho i had to google the exact usage, it helped...

Comment: show your storyboard and are working with constrain ?

Comment: the controller is called programmatically, so there is no storyboard to show. and yes. with constraints.

Comment: what is the size of your tableview ? right now with this output

Comment: `tableView.frame.size.height = 736.0`

Comment: tableview.frame.size.height = self.view.frame.size.height change this and check output.

Comment: same issue and same console output. if you have a look at the earlier comment, we've already found, that contentInset does the trick. but i thank you for your help and effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is create a global constant and set the UIEdgeInsetsMake(), for example:

```
let collectionViewInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 44, 0)
```

44 is the height of the navigation bar, and you need to start it after the navigationBar, so y = 44.0.

After doing that you need to set:

```
collectionView.contentInset = collectionViewInset
```

And that's it, sorted!